# Prevent enforcing password policy on non domain Windows 10 after adding corporate mail account?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, group-policy, password-management

The question is mostly in the subject - I have a home Windows 10 pro installation (with the very latest November update as of this post) that's obviously not on my company domain. I want to add my company's Office 365 account to use the Mail and Calendar metro apps.
When I do so, it tells me that it will enforce company policy regarding password complexity, history and expiry. Is there a way to prevent this?

"Try using `gpedit.msc`" is not an option - when I open it, the existing values for password policy (no complexity, history or expiry) are untouched.